# fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory (on Windows 11)

Tags: avr, stm32

So I'm using arduino 1.8.18 installed on zip file. I am using the HardWire library. The project is the STM32 quadcopter by joop brokking. http://www.brokking.net/ymfc-32_downloads.html

complete error -

```
Arduino: 1.8.18 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic STM32F103C series, STM32F103C8 (20k RAM. 64k Flash), Serial, 72Mhz (Normal), Smallest (default)"

C:\Users\ishaa\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HardWire\src\utility\twi.c:26:20: fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory

Multiple libraries were found for "Wire.h"

 #include <avr/io.h>

 Used: C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\arduino-1.8.18\hardware\Arduino_STM32-master\STM32F1\libraries\Wire
                    ^
 Not used: C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\arduino-1.8.18\hardware\Arduino_STM32-master\STM32F1\libraries\WireSlave

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Generic STM32F103C series.
```

As you can see I'm using the stm32 lib by roger clark. The ide is unable to detect any of the avr/.h files. I tried replacing the path in twi.c, but then the other avr files start giving errors.

Why is this happening?

Comment: For this arduino ide you can add  portable  directory (arduino-1.8.18\portable) and add only cores/libraries you want to use for STM32. Or just delete all colliding libraries